# Jack ERROR while building AOSP Extended ROM

Tags: android-source, rom, jack, android-rom

I'm trying to build **Aosp Extended oreo ROM** for Leeco le 2(s2)

I have a Google Cloud platform VM with **16GB RAM, 4cores**. I searched for similar cases but couldn't find anything. I also asked XDA, Reddit, Custom Rom development telegram groups but didn't get the solution.

> Device tree:
> https://github.com/kegang0619/device_leeco_s2/tree/master/leeco/s2
>
> Vendor tree:= https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_leeco
>
> Kernel Source:= https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_leeco_msm8976

[Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/kiqobiraga.coffeescript)

That is the error. *I couldn't post the code directly here. Sorry*

When I try to build a ROM, it appears.

So, I ran **Fuck Jack!** (https://github.com/mikecriggs/fuckjack) and it shows this error.

[FuckJack result Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/makewotaga.sql)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the Jack toolchain is deprecated. Jack was the default Android build toolchain for Android 6.0–8.1. However, it can be still used for the build system.

From the error logs, it seems jack server is not running.

```
Jack server jar "prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar" is not readable
Jack server installation not found
```

Please make sure if above path(**prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar**) exists and readable by the build system.

For more details, please refer https://source.android.com/setup/build/jack